# Micro JST 1.25 to any raspberry pi or RPI 4?

Tags: pi-4, connection, connectors

I'm Making a raspberry pi project, and I want to connect a Micro JST 1.25 to a raspberry pi.
I already got a Micro JST 1.25 cable, but I need to connect it to a raspberry pi to operate it. I searched in Amazon and Google and found nothing but extender cables for it. Is it possible to find a small circuit or adapter to connect a Micro JST 1.25 to an RPI?

Comment: What is the purpose of the cable? What will it be used for?

Comment: It will be used to control a brushless motor with raspberry pi.

Comment: I presume it would be hard to find an oddly specific adapter cable. What's preventing you from snipping it off and soldering/twisting on compatible headers (such as breadboard jumper cables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the JST connectors I used for my projects, but you will need to crimp them small enough:

[Litorange 500PCS 2.54mm 2/3/4/5/6 Pin Housing JST Adapter Cable Connector Socket Male and Female JST-XH Connector Kit with Female Pin Terminal Connector Kit](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B087CPV5T4)

I just use some breadboard jumpers and snip off one end and leave the female end for the GPIO pins.

Here is a shot of a project I use them on with a Raspberry Pi Pico.

[image: JST connectors with Raspberry Pi Pico]

Comment: 1 more question. is it possible to control the motors with the RPi?

Comment: If they are 3 3 v and less than 500mA combined and using gpiozero python library then yes you can. If not maybe have to use either a motor driver or npn transistors and capacitors.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to cut the cable in the middle and attach jumper wires compatible with RPi instead of the connector.

Another option is to modify whatever is at the other end of the cable to use the same pins as the RPi, and then simply use jumper wires to connect the two.

Adaptors are unlikely to exist because you will want to choose to which pins you connect, so every project will need a different adapter.